# Volume form on a manifold.

Tags: volume, differential-forms

On a manifold M, we define the volume form to be

$vol = \sqrt{|det(g)|}dx^{1}\wedge...\wedge dx^{n}$. Where g is the metric.

But I don't really understand this definition. Why the square-root of the determinant?

Comment: determinant of **what**?

Comment: Determinant of the metric.

Comment: I guess "vol" should be a coordinate independent object, right?

Comment: Theres a good explanation of this in Baez & Munians *Knots & Gravity* - I was looking at it today.

Comment: Look up the Gram determinant. The purpose of the Riemannian volume form is that if $X_1(p), X_2(p), \cdots, X_n(p)$ is a basis of orthonormal vectors in the inner product space $T_p M$ with inner product $g_p$, then $\text{vol}(X_1(p), \cdots, X_n(p)) = 1$.

Comment: You can try to show that it is in fact coordinate independent.

Answer (score 3):

A Riemannian manifold has a canonically defined volume form, which is given by the above form $\text{vol}=\sqrt{\text{det}\,g}\,\text{d}x^1\wedge...\wedge\text{d}x^n$:

Given an arbitrary, positively oriented, chart $(U,x^1,...,x^n)$, *apply the Gram-Schmidt process* to the coordinate frame $\big\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\big\}$ to get an orthonormal frame, and then let $\{\theta^1,...,\theta^n\}$ be the frame dual to this orthonormal frame.  Then
$$
\omega=\theta^1\wedge...\wedge\theta^n
$$
is a nowhere vanishing $n$-form on $U$ which does not depend on the choice of positively oriented chart.  This means that if $(V,y^1,...,y^n)$ is another positively oriented, overlapping chart with coordinate frame $\big\{\frac{\partial}{\partial y^1},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial y^n}\big\}$, then by applying the Gram-Schmidt process to get an orthonormal frame, and letting $\{\alpha^1,...,\alpha^n\}$ be the frame dual to the orthonormal frame, we also have that $\omega=\alpha^1\wedge...\wedge\alpha^n$ on the intersection $U\cap V$.

We can then show that $\omega$ coincides with the volume form given above:
$$
\omega=\text{vol}=\sqrt{\text{det}\,g}\,\text{d}x^1\wedge...\wedge\text{d}x^n,
$$
where $\{\text{d}x^1,...,\text{d}x^n\}$ is the frame dual to $\big\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\big\}$.